# Data not insert and update through ajax and jQuery in admin page?

Tags: plugin-development, ajax, jquery, wp-admin

I made custom plugin and done crud operation, display all data in admin page, used ajax and jquery. Data successfully deleted but not inserted or updated. Data successfully pass through ajax but not inserted.
Also What I saw if input block is empty and I put some data and updated it. It got first row data.
Error- https://prnt.sc/wnzqjr
ajax for insert the data

```
jQuery('.ins_btn').click(function(){
        var id = jQuery(this).attr('data-id');
        var question = jQuery('#question').val();
        var answer = jQuery('#answer').val();
        // alert(id);
        $.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php');?>', 
            type: 'POST',
            data:{ 
              action: 'insert_records', 
              insert_record : id,
              insert_question: question,
              insert_answer: answer
            },
            success: function( data ){
                alert("Records are successfully insert");
                location.reload();
            }
         });
    });
```

insert query

```
 function insert_records(){
  global $wpdb;
 $id = $_POST['insert_record'];
 $question = $_POST['insert_question'];
 $answer = $_POST['insert_answer'];


  $db_inserted = $wpdb->insert( $wpdb->prefix.'faqq', 
        array( 'ID' => $id, 
               'question' => $question, 
               'answer' => $answer) 
    );
}
add_action( "wp_ajax_insert_records", "insert_records" );
add_action( "wp_ajax_nopriv_insert_records", "insert_records" );
```

ajax for update the data

```
jQuery('.upd_btn').click(function(){
        var id = jQuery(this).attr('data-id');
        var question = jQuery('#question').val();
        var answer = jQuery('#answer').val();
        alert(question);
        $.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php');?>', 
            type: 'POST',
            data:{ 
              action: 'update_records', 
              update_record : id,
              update_question : question,
              update_answer : answer

            },
            success: function( data ){
                alert("Records are successfully updated");
                location.reload();
            }
         });
    });
```

update query

```
function update_records(){
  global $wpdb;
  // $table_name = $wpdb->prefix.'faqq';
  $id = $_POST['update_record'];
  $question = $_POST['update_question'];
  $answer = $_POST['update_answer'];
  $db_updated = $wpdb->update( $wpdb->prefix.'faqq', 
        array('question'    => $question,
              'answer'   => $answer, array( 'ID' => $id ) )
          ); 
}
```

this is html code

```
        <form method="POST" action=""  > 
            <table>
                 <td><?php echo $print->id ?></td>
                 <td>
                    <input type="text" name="question" id="question"  value="<?php echo $print->question ?>" ></td>
                 <td>
                 <input type="text" name="answer" id="answer"  value="<?php echo $print->answer ?>" > </td>
                 <td>
                    <input type="button" value="Insert" id="insert" data-id = "<?php echo $print->id ?>" name="insert" class="ins_btn">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="button" value="Update" id="update" data-id = "<?php echo $print->id ?>" name="update" class="upd_btn">
                </td>
                 <td>
                    <input type="button" value="Delete" id="delete" data-id = "<?php echo $print->id ?>" name="delete" class="del_btn">
                </td>
            </table>
        </form>
```

Here are some errors.
1)Getting error when update the data through ajax- https://prnt.sc/wnymkx,
https://prnt.sc/wnyos5, https://prnt.sc/wnyuhk

Comment: You don’t specify which table to update and insert the data to, that the first thing that jumped out to me, just the db prefix.

Comment: $wpdb->prefix.'faqq' is table name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that there's an *internal server error* (see [screenshot](https://prnt.sc/wnymkx)) when you tried to *update* a record in the database, and the error is likely because you **incorrectly called [`$wpdb->update()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/update/)** which has the syntax of — and note that the first three parameters (`$table`, `$data` and `$where`) are *required*:

`wpdb::update( string $table, array $data, array $where, array|string $format = null, array|string $where_format = null )`

But in your code, you did not set the **third parameter** (`$where`):

```php
// In update_records():
$db_updated = $wpdb->update( $wpdb->prefix.'faqq',
    array( 'question' => $question,
           'answer'   => $answer, array( 'ID' => $id ) )
);
```

And I guess the `array( 'ID' => $id )` is the `$where` part, but you probably made a typo which resulted in that part being part of the second parameter instead.

So fix that and your code would work properly. Example:

```php
$db_updated = $wpdb->update( $wpdb->prefix.'faqq',
    array( 'question' => $question,
           'answer'   => $answer,
    ),
    array( 'ID' => $id )
);
```

As for your `insert_records()` function, it looks fine to me, so there shouldn't be an issue when inserting new records to your database table.

Additionally, you should also (later) do things like data sanitization and call `wp_die()` to end the AJAX request, and fix the issue as seen [here](https://prnt.sc/wnyuhk).

Comment: Yes, you are right. There is mistake in update query which I corrected. Now data updated but getting first row data. Screenshot - https://prnt.sc/wokuuk

Comment: Well, for that one, you need to show how you're outputting the data, i.e. show your *form* HTML and the relevant PHP code.

Comment: I added html code in above code. please have a look @Sally Cj.

Comment: Please add all PHP you used in that form - where/how you defined the `$print`, how you query your table (what PHP code you use), show any `foreach`/`for` loop, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I did wrong code in ajax and jquery-
for update function in ajax and jQuery (Before)-

```
jQuery('.upd_btn').click(function(){
        var id = jQuery(this).attr('data-id');
        
        var question = jQuery('#question').val();
        var answer = jQuery('#answer').val();
        
        $.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php');?>', 
            type: 'POST',
            data:{ 
              action: 'update_records', 
              update_record : id,
              update_question : question,
              update_answer : answer

            },
            success: function( data ){
                // alert("Records are successfully updated");
                // location.reload();
            }
         });
    });
```

After
What I did wrong was I got the same id for question('#question') and answer('#answer') column. So I got the first row data for any row
Here is the answer

```
jQuery('.upd_btn').click(function(){
        var id = jQuery(this).attr('data-id');
        
        var question = jQuery(this).closest('table').find('.question').val();
        var answer = jQuery(this).closest('table').find('.answer').val();
        
        $.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php');?>', 
            type: 'POST',
            data:{ 
              action : 'update_records', 
              update_record : id,
              update_question : question,
              update_answer : answer

            },
            success: function( data ){
                // alert("Records are successfully updated");
                
            }
         });
    });
```

So I changed id value and get class of each field and use closest function.

Comment: Update issue solved. Thank you @Sally CJ

Comment: Yes, I did notice that (`#question` and `#answer` issue in your JS) before I posted my answer, but I was hoping to see more of your form HTML before commenting on that duplicate ID's. Anyway, glad that you figured it out. Happy coding!